# Prove that $\displaystyle{\int{(F(x+c)-F(x))}\,\mathrm dx=c\mu (\mathbb{R})}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a finite measure space ($\mu$ is finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$)  If $F(x)=\mu ((-\infty,x])$ and $c>0$ prove that $$\displaystyle{\int{(F(x+c)-F(x))}\,\mathrm dx=c\mu (\mathbb{R})}.$$

Comment: We're not here to solve your problems. It would be better if you added what you've tried to do to prove that.

Comment: What role does $\varphi$ play in the problem statement? Have you noticed that $f(x+c)-F(x)=\mu((x,x+c])$?

Comment: I'm really sorry but to be honest it's my homework from the class I've missed and I still don't know how to deal with it.Could you at least recommend what textbook(also what chapter) or theorem I can apply here?

Comment: Do you know Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Is it because $((-\infty,x])\cap (x,x+c])=\phi$ so $\mu ((-\infty,x+c])=\mu ((-\infty,x])+\mu ((x,x+c])$? and then?

Comment: Is it about when we can find the value of $\int{|f(x,y)|}dxdy$ then the value $\int{f(x,y)}dxdy=\int{f(x,y)}dydx$?

Comment: But Isn't there only one variable here?

Comment: Not if you write the integral as $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}\chi_{\{(s,t),s< t\leqslant s+c\}}\mathrm{d}\mu(t)\mathrm ds$.

Comment: I know that $\chi $is the characteristic function but why does the integral in the problem equal to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}{...}$ here?

Comment: What is the inner integral?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9742/discussion-between-user76608-and-davide-giraudo)

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I read the problem as finding
$\int_{X} F(x+c)-F(x) \, d\mu(x)$ with $X\subset \mathbb{R}$. This brings me to two questions. First, can we automatically assume a finite Borel measure preserves lengths of intervals (i.e. $\mu((x,x+c])=c$)? It seems this would cause the integral to equal $c\mu(X)$ because $F(x+c)-F(x)=c$ for all $x\in X$. Why is this not a correct line of thinking?

Comment: It is not necessarily the case that $\mu(x,x+c]=c$ (actually, there is a characterization of Lebesgue measure).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo It's also unclear to me if the original integral is actually the Lebesgue integral or not over $\mathbb{R}$, which I think you imply in your comment. If that was the case, then the solution makes sense. You write it was $\int_\mathbb{R^2} \chi d\mu(t) ds$. Does the $ds$ represent the standard Lebesgue integral? If that is the case, I do think it is unnecessary to have called the measure space $X$ and do not see the reason why besides the question is poorly worded.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the discussion in the comments I'll post here the sketch of the solution
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} (F(x+c)-F(x))d\lambda(x)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \mu((x,x+c])d\lambda(x)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{(x,x+c]}(t) d\mu(t)d\lambda(x)\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{(x,x+c]}(t) d\lambda(x)d\mu(t)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}c d\mu(t)
=c\mu(\mathbb{R})
$$